# Problem finding the longest slope of descending series in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I was asked in my course to solve the following problem:

Given a matrix of m*n  of positive numbers a "slope" is a series of k cells which each one is adjacent to its previous (up, right, left or down but not diagonally) so that the values are a decreasing invoice series with difference of "num" (num is provided, num > 0).

I need to find the longest slope in the matrix using a recursive function.
Here's my code:

```
public static int longestSlope(int[][] mat, int num){
    return longestSlope(mat,num,0,0, mat[0][0]);
}


public static int longestSlope(int[][] mat, int num, int row, int col, int prev_val){
    //This function runs over each cell in the matrix
    if (row < 0 || row >= mat.length || col < 0 || col >= mat[0].length)
        return 0;
    int right, down;
    right = longestSlope1(mat, num, row, col + 1, mat[row][col]);
    down = longestSlope1(mat, num, row + 1, col, mat[row][col]);
    return Math.max(right, down);
}

public static int longestSlope1(int[][] mat, int num, int row, int col, int prev_val){
    //This function runs over each cell and checks the "Slopes"
    //that begin from that particular cell
    if (row < 0 || row >= mat.length || col < 0 || col >= mat[0].length)
        return 0;
    int right = 1, down = 1, left = 1, up = 1;
    if(mat[row][col] == prev_val - num) {
        right += 1 + longestSlope1(mat, num, row, col + 1, mat[row][col]);
        down += 1 + longestSlope1(mat,num,row + 1, col, mat[row][col]);
        left += 1 + longestSlope1(mat, num, row, col - 1, mat[row][col]);
        up += 1 + longestSlope1(mat, num, row - 1, col, mat[row][col]);
    }
    else return 0;
    return Math.max(Math.max(down, up), Math.max(right, left));
}
```

I got 0 in my actual result, can anyone please try and see the problem? I don't manage to find it using my debugger. I'm grateful for your help and assistance.

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include comments in your code

Comment: I've added some comments, tell me if you need any more documentation

Comment: It would be polite if the comments would be visible in a standard browser window without scrolling. It would be helpful if you would describe the algorithm  you are trying to implement, as this is a Java site, not a math site.